# Validating memory read from eeprom/flash memory

Tags: memory

How can one validate the data/contents read from memory[eeprom/flash] is correct or not?

What i have done is,
1.) read_mem(location, readBuf1,128)
2.) read_mem(location, readBuf2,128)
3.) if 0 == memcmp(readBuf1,readaBuf2,128), then VALID else INVALID

What are Pros and Cons of above steps?
Any another ways to do it?

Comment: Is this an academic assignment?

Answer (score 3):

If the contents ot the memory are corrupted, reading them twice won't help. The usual method to validate memory contents is using additional data like checksum or CRC

Answer (score 1):

If reliability is an issue, one can use a flash memory that has builtin
checksums.  [32 MB flash with ECC](http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/CAT24C256-D.PDF)

Simple redundancy is NOT a good test; if a data bit were stuck high or low,
it would pass that test.  At least, invert the bits.